# el-datepicker refocus after selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I have a form with a datepicker inside. I would like to be able to trigger my search-function on keydown.enter. The problem is that the datepicker loses focus after selecting a date. If I try to refocus the datepicker, the calendar-popup won't close. Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: Yes becoz the popup is designed to show up when focussed

Comment: why do you want to change that, what's the requirement, realtime use case?

Comment: @Amaarrockz my users would like to be able to trigger the search by hitting the enter key. I can do that with all the normal input fields (using @keydown.native.enter) but haven't figured a way out for the datepicker. My thought was to refocus the datepicker after selecting the date and add a method to it that fires on enter.